# Different results by attr and data

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p id="getMessage" data-sid="158">
  <strong>Name</strong> : Rahul Kumar<br>
  <strong>Total </strong> : 25<br>
</p>
```

This is my dynamically generated HTML using jQuery

Now this is stable and fix

I executed several commands in Consol and found these results

```
$('#getMessage').attr('data-sid');
"158"
```

This is as expected.

But when I execute this

```
$('#getMessage').data('sid');
160
```

It shows 160, it should be 158 right ?

I used `$('#getMessage').attr('data-sid', result.studentDetails.SID);` to set it.

Comment: a simple test will show you that it returns the same result, you might have something else going on in your code...

Comment: The results are the same, see https://jsfiddle.net/syjtqp30/. Do you have another element with the id getMessage on your page?

Comment: Works great for me: http://output.jsbin.com/pesoki Maybe something else overide this value.

Comment: you can show us working demo of not working. It should work.

Comment: @Vohuman this is a different question and I found the answer too see the comments in Jamiec answer.

Comment: @RahulKumar This isn't a different question. This _is_ a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.attr` will read the *actual attribute*.

`.data` will read the *current value of that data item*. If you have code which has changed the value (ie, `$('#getMessage').data('sid',160)`) that will be the current value.

Comment: If it is updated. It will update in HTML too right ?

Comment: @RahulKumar absolutely not

Comment: @RahulKumar: It will update data property and not attribute value. And that is the reason it is not reflected in attributes.

Comment: @RahulKumar for reflecting in html you need to use `attr()` method

Comment: I used this to update my html

$('#getMessage').attr('data-sid', result.studentDetails.SID);

so first time it set data to 160

When second time I executed this it only changed my data attribute value not the actual data right?

Comment: @RahulKumar as others have said, if updating the html was your goal you should use `.attr`. If storing/updating some arbitrary data in an element use `.data`

Comment: My Goal was to update data so I should use .data instead of attr

Comment: Yes, but then dont expect your html to reflect the change!

Answer (score 0):

The `data()` function stores data to a specific element

> Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element and/or return the value that was set.

```
jQuery.data($('#element'), data);
```

On the other hand, `attr()` gets or sets attributes form the element.

```
$('div').attr('data-test', 'test');

<div data-test="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as requested a working example..., notice that i can change the value of the data attribute without changing the actual attribute

```js
console.log($('#getMessage').attr('data-sid'));
console.log($('#getMessage').data('sid'));

$('#getMessage').data('sid', 160);

console.log($('#getMessage').attr('data-sid'));
console.log($('#getMessage').data('sid'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="getMessage" data-sid="158">
  <strong>Name</strong> : Rahul Kumar
  <br>
  <strong>Total </strong> : 25
  <br>
</p>
```